# Convergence in Probability

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, convergence

In the following question, I was able to compute part (i), and part (ii), but I am finding hard time to compute with part (iii).

[image]

So far I have computed the MLE of $\theta$, which is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i -n}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - M} $

I was trying to use the following concept for convergence

[image: following concept for convergence]

but I am finding it hard to proceed. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you post your answers to (i) and (ii) either here or as a separate question/answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convergence in probability means

$$\operatorname{plim}(\hat \theta) = \theta$$

The $\operatorname{plim}(\hat \theta)$ is straightforward to compute:

$$\operatorname{plim}(\hat \theta) = \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i -n}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - M}\right)$$

and multiplying numerator and denominator by $\frac 1n$ we obtain, using the continuous transformation mapping and the LLN

$$\operatorname{plim}(\hat \theta) = \frac {E(Y) - 1}{E(Y)-P(Y=r+1)}$$

Note that 
$$P(Y=r+1) = \operatorname{plim}(M/n) = P(X>r) = 1-P(X\le r)$$

and so

$$\operatorname{plim}(\hat \theta) = \frac {E(Y) - 1}{E(Y)-1+P(X\le r)}$$

which provides a nice intuition. Now since you have computed the **pmf** of $Y$ you should be able to show that

$$\operatorname{plim}(\hat \theta) = \frac {E(Y) - 1}{E(Y)-1+P(X\le r)} = \theta$$

**ADDENDUM**
Note that what is denoted $p$ in the textbook formulation of the geometric distribution (the probability of "success"), in your formulation it is $1-\theta$. So we have

$$P(X\le r) = 1-\theta^{\,r}$$

So we want to check whether

$$\operatorname{plim}(\hat \theta) = \frac {E(Y) - 1}{E(Y)-\theta^{\,r}} =?\; \theta \Rightarrow (1-\theta)E(Y) =?\; 1-\theta^{\,r+1} \qquad [A]$$

The variable $Y$ can be written, using indicator functions, as

$$Y = X\cdot I_{\{X\le r\}} + (r+1)(1-I_{\{X\le r\}})$$

So, using the properties of indicator functions

$$E(Y) =E\left( X\cdot I_{\{X\le r\}}\right) + (r+1)\left(1-P(X\le r)\right) = E\left( X\cdot I_{\{X\le r\}}\right)+(r+1)\theta^{\,r}$$

Consider now the variable $Z=X\cdot I_{\{X\le r\}}$.This variable takes the values of $X$ when $X\le r$ and the value $0$ otherwise. So we have immediatelly

$$E(Z) = E\left( X\cdot I_{\{X\le r\}}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^rk(1-\theta)\theta^{\,k-1}= \frac {1-\theta}{\theta}\sum_{k=1}^rk\theta^{\,k}$$

The value of this finite sum is (look it up, for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series))
$$\sum_{k=1}^rk\theta^{\,k} =  \theta\frac{1-(r+1)\theta^{\,r}+r\theta^{\,r+1}}{(1-\theta)^2}$$

Simplifying we obtain

$$E(Z) = E\left( X\cdot I_{\{X\le r\}}\right) =\frac{1-(r+1)\theta^{\,r}+r\theta^{\,r+1}}{1-\theta} $$

So the LHS of eq. $[A]$ becomes

$$(1-\theta)E(Y) = 1-(r+1)\theta^{\,r}+r\theta^{\,r+1}+(1-\theta)(r+1)\theta^{\,r}$$

$$=1-(r+1)\theta^{\,r}+r\theta^{\,r+1}+(r+1)\theta^{\,r}-(r+1)\theta^{\,r+1}$$
Simplifying we obtain

$$(1-\theta)E(Y)=1-\theta^{\,r+1}$$

which is exactly what we wanted to verify, in order to show that the estimator is consistent.

On the side, note the interesting thing here that the above implies that $E(Y) = 1+\theta^2+...+ \theta^{\,r}$, which should be intuitive, since as $r \rightarrow \infty$ (no failure), $E(Y) \rightarrow \frac {1}{1-\theta}=E(X)$.

Comment: Could you clarify following step:$$P(Y=r+1) = \operatorname{plim}(M/n) = P(X>r) = 1-P(X\le r)$$

Comment: By the question, $M$ is the number of $Y-$ realizations that take the value $r+1$. Then $M/n$ is a consistent estimator of the probability that $Y$ takes the value $r+1$ (we implicitly assume that this probability is bounded away from zero and from unity). So $\operatorname{plim}(M/n) = P(Y=r+1)$. But the probability of $Y$ acquiring the value $r+1$ is equal to the probability that $X$ is greater than $r$.

Comment: I am lost in calculations, still finding it hard to compute:
I got $E(Y)= [M(1-\theta)+1]\sum_{y=1}^n y\theta^{(y-1)}$
Also, $P(X\leq r) = \sum_{x=1}^r \theta^{x-1}(1-\theta) = M(1-\theta)\sum_{x=1}^M \theta^{x-1}$
[I doubt in my calculation for $P(X\leq r)$]. I put them altogether and then used the standard form for $\sum_{y=1}^n y \theta^{(y-1)}$. But still no where close to $\theta$. Could you please confirm whether I am following the steps right?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos It was really helpful to see step by step approach. Thank you!

Comment: @Andy Thanks Andy. My answer seems to have also helped the OP, which is a good thing.